# Decrease Thinkpad resolution

Tags: display-resolution, thinkpad

I have a [Lenovo Thinkpad T520](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t520) with a 1920x1080 display. Everything is too small and I wand to change resolution to 1600x900. Is there any way to do this or do I have to change my display to a 1600x900 screen? I don't know how to end this posting but I've given up an being able to use Ubuntu. I tried to get a file from my shared windows drive and was no longer able to access it. please terminate this post.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  Changing resolution is not a good solution to your problem, but scaling is. Please advise which version of Ubuntu and which release number you have. The default desktop environments for some versions can scale much better than others. Please click [edit] to reply. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].